# How to extend the topmenu.php block in magento2

Tags: magento2, topmenu

I'm trying to extend the topmenu.php block to make some modifications but it doesn't work for me.

I already created my custom module.

Can someone help me by explaining how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

First Of all, you need to assign your create block into the layout default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
      <block class=“Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!**!

Comment: Hello, it's the topmenu.php file, not the .phtml